# Programmatically attach scroll="false" for ion-content

Tags: ionic-framework, angular-directive

Is there any way to programmatically attach `scroll="false"` attribute for ion-content, with the help of a directive or other?

We need to hide the default behavior of ionic scroll while the application loading in web.

Thanks..

Comment: <ion-content scroll="false"> should work

Comment: Hi, my question is, how to attach it using code(at run time)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use

> $ionicScrollDelegate

.

```
$ionicScrollDelegate.$getByHandle('Add Your div Handle').
 getScrollView().options.scrollingY = false;
```

For more reference,
http://ionicframework.com/docs/v1/api/service/%24ionicScrollDelegate/